# How to tc filter with NETEM?

Tags: networking

I need some help directing netem delays to a specific IP. I have inputted all the commands correctly with no errors and as shown in the pictures attached. I have no latency being added to my speed tests. For further information when I used the command: "tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms" the delays are added flawlessly. What am I doing wrong ?

P.S. I am a beginner at using TC and NETEM, so please if any solutions are given please be thorough when explaining.

Here are some screenshots for a better understanding towards my problem:

http://postimg.org/image/k9pu6uhxv/
http://postimg.org/image/tis0gyqtv/

Comment: i wonder if 192.168.2.X is still your destination ip on interface eth1 ( we don't have your interfaces configuration ).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbit
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 flowid 1:1 match ip dst 192.168.2.219
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem delay 25ms 5ms
```

- PS: by adding 5ms jitter to delay, you also create packet reordering
  in the network. Assuming that this is what you want.
- PPS: I am not    sure whether adding jitter creates reordering or not
  in OpenWRT. But    it surely does in the Linux kernel. Netem has undergone umpteen number of changes since 2010.
- PPPS: To introduce jitter w/o    packet reordering, set a very high
  rate limit.

  ```
  tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: rate 1000 mbit netem delay 25ms 5ms
  ```

Comment: What exactly does the "flowid 1:1" declare in the 4th line of code written by user2283864 ?

Comment: For a complete understanding of netem, I suggest you refer to this  [Master thesis.](http://home.ifi.uio.no/paalh/students/AndersMoe.pdf)

Comment: http://tcn.hypert.net/tcmanual.pdf