# NetEm IPv4 filtering

Tags: networking, udp, iptables, tcp, iproute

Hope I've came to the right place to ask this, if not I guess my question becomes where can I find people who know the answer as a week on google doesnt help!

I have NetEm setup and got it finally working but what I want to do is test using an IPv4 filter, i.e I want to have latency added to one IP without adding it to others to test the effect of a range of different latencies all commected to one server.

Im running NetEm through ubuntu, any advice pointing me to the right direction would help!

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: I mean external IP's btw.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below set of commands to setup netem to do whatever you want for a particular ip address.

`tc qdisc del dev eth0 root`

(assuming eth0 is the interface)

`tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb`

`tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbit`

(100mbit rate of tokens)

`tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 flowid 1:1 match ip dst 192.168.2.219`

(assuming you want to throttle bw for this dst ip address)

`tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem delay 25ms`

(assuming you want a 25ms delay)

Refer to my other answer for a better [explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729545/how-to-tc-filter-with-netem/24922028#24922028)

And this excellent [thesis](http://home.ifi.uio.no/paalh/students/AndersMoe.pdf) for a better understanding